# Problem with counting null values in 'if statement' in R

Tags: r, if-statement, null, arima

I am passing some data to a simple code block in R which counts the null values and then performs an ARIMA time series imputation. I have written a very simple 'if' statement which counts the null values in the time series, and if they are less than a certain amount, ignores that column and moves on to the next one (as the ARIMA imputation requires a certain amount of non-null data to work, otherwise it returns an error). Counting the nulls seems to work fine, but the if statement is behaving very strangely and not working. I included a print statement to count the nulls inside and outside the if statement, but the if statement is passing the code to the loop when the if statement is not fulfilled. Here is the code and the output:

```
stations <- c('BX1', 'BX2', 'BG3') # each station has a different data file
pollutants <- c('nox','no2','pm10','pm25') # each station contains data on a number of pollutants
for (s in stations) {
  print(paste('starting imputation for station ', s, sep=" "))
  s_result <- read.csv(paste("/path/to/file", s, "_rescaled.csv", sep=""))
  for (p in pollutants) {
    ts = c()
    pcol = paste0(p,"_iqr",sep="") # find the right column
    ts = s_result[[pcol]]  # get the time series from the column
    print(pcol) # check which pollutant we're working on
    print(length(ts)) # test the length of the time series
    print(sum(is.na(ts))) # test the number of nulls in the time series
    if (sum(is.na(ts) != length(ts))) {       # if the time series is not completely null
      print(sum(is.na(ts)))            # check the length of the time series again for testing
      usermodel <- arima(ts, order = c(10, 1, 0))$model      # calculate the arima
      p_result <- na_kalman(ts, model = usermodel, maxgap = 24)    # calculate the arima
      s_result <- cbind(s_result,p_result) # add the computed column to the dataframe
      names(s_result)[names(s_result) == "p_result"] <- paste0(p,"_imputed",sep ="")
    } else { # otherwise add a null column
      p_result <- c(NA, length=length(ts))
      s_result <- cbind(s_result,p_result) # enter a null column
      names(s_result)[names(s_result) == "p_result"] <- paste0(p,"_imputed",sep ="")
    }
  }
  filename = paste0("/path/to/file", s, "_imputed_test.csv", sep="")
  write.csv(s_result, filename, row.names = TRUE) 
  print(paste('completed imputation for station ', s, sep=" "))
}
```

The problem is, that this if statement is not working correctly as it is passing data to the arima imputation inside the if statement even when the number of nulls is equal to the length of the time series. Here's the output:

```
[1] "starting imputation for station  BG1"
[1] "nox_iqr"
[1] 17520
[1] 4660
[1] 4660
[1] "no2_iqr"
[1] 17520
[1] 4664
[1] 4664
[1] "pm10_iqr"
[1] 17520
[1] 17520
[1] 17520
Error in arima(ts, order = c(10, 1, 0)) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Clearly something is wrong, as for the pm10 pollutant, there are 17520 nulls, the same as the length of the time series. Therefore the if statement should not run the line counting the number of nulls again inside the 'if' statement, as this line of code should be bypassed. ie. for the time series relating to column pm10_iqr, the number of nulls is 17520, the length of the time series is 17520, and this would cause the arima to fail - hence the if statement should skip this line. But it does not do this.

Where am I going wrong please? This should be very simple but it does not make any sense! I don't write alot of R code, usually Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/how-to-count-the-missing-value-in-r/2949/5

Comment: `sum(is.na(ts) != length(ts))` should probably be `sum(is.na(ts)) != length(ts)` -> note the closing parenthesis for the `sum` expression! We want to compare the **sum** of `is.na(ts)` ...

Comment: @dario, sorry I don't understand. Please can you explain the syntax? I'm using R studio, I get a syntax error if I make that replacement.

Comment: @LucieCBurgess In your example code, you write `if (sum(is.na(ts) != length(ts))) { ` which in R means: `if` the sum of `is.na(ts) != length(ts)` then do something. What you probably *wanted* to say is: `if` the sum of `is.na(ts)` is not the same as the length of `ts`, then do something.

Comment: @dario, I misread your answer (due to the ->) - I thought you meant to replace the curly bracket with ->. Thanks, this seems to work. Phew, I thought I was going totally crazy with this one! Will mark as answered. THANK YOU

Comment: Also in R, any number other than `0` evaluates to TRUE (i.e. `if (0) {print("evaluated to TRUE")} else {print("evaluated to FALSE")}` and `if (5) {print("evaluated to TRUE")} else {print("evaluated to FALSE")}`

Comment: @dario can't see where to accept your answer as it's a comment I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(is.na(ts) != length(ts))
```

should probably be

```
sum(is.na(ts)) != length(ts))
```

Explanation what went wrong: In R, any number other than 0 evaluates to TRUE. For example:

```
if (0) {print("evaluated to TRUE")} else {print("evaluated to FALSE")} and
```

Returns:

```
 [1] "evaluated to FALSE"
```

and:

```
if (5) {print("evaluated to TRUE")} else {print("evaluated to FALSE")}
```

Returns:

```
[1] "evaluated to TRUE"
```

**Additionally**, R accepts booleans (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) as arguments to `sum` (and other arithmetic functions) and treats them in these cases as 1 (`TRUE`) and 0 (`FALSE`).

```
is.na(ts) != length(ts)
```

Evaluates to some vector of TRUEs and FALSEs

and

```
sum(is.na(ts) != length(ts))
```

happily sums them up ;)

That's why your code didn't raise any errors, because it was *kind of* working, just not doing what we meant it to do... these are my most feared errors ;)

Comment: thank you, very well-explained answer - and glad I'm not going crazy as this bug really bugged me :-)

Comment: @LucieCBurgess It's a common mistake I've made many times myself ;)